# Select top 1 from multiple records SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2008

How to apply `CROSS APPLY` function for the below script? I would like to retrieve TOP 1 for each multiple records.

```
select s.UnitID
      ,p.PartNumber
      ,po.ProductionOrderNumber
      ,s.[Value] as  SerialNumber
      ,p.Revision
      ,case ush.UnitStatusID
         when 0
           then 'Processing'
         else 'Completed'
       end as UnitStatusID
      ,ush.[Time] as LastUpdate
      ,ush.LooperCount
from ffpart as p
    join ffProductionOrder as po
        on p.ID = po.PartID
    join ffUnitDetail as ud
        on po.ID = ud.ProductionOrderID
    join ffSerialNumber as s
        on ud.UnitID = s.UnitID
    join ffUnitStatusHistory as ush
        on ud.UnitID = ush.UnitID
where s.[Value] in('ACNX4853'
                ,'ACRA3259'
                ,'AY1712466664'
                )
order by ush.[Time] desc;
```

Appreciate for your answer.. Thanks in advance.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: What do you mean by *TOP 1 for each multiple records*?  How are you grouping you data?  Which results do you only want one record for?  Please be more specific, ideally including a sample of the results you are currently getting and the output you are trying to achieve.

Comment: right now for single record retrieve multiple output. So I would like to retrieve latest record based on LastUpdate  column and  [order by LastUpdate column desc]

Answer (score 0):

script showing output as attached and I want to retrieve only which is highlighted in green [order by **LastUpdate** column desc]

[Script Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wFpEC.jpg)